# How to know the final program size after compilation on avr32

Tags: size, avr32-gcc

I am using avr studio 5. My controller is AT32UC3A0512. I want to know my final program size which will be occupied on flash before burning the program. Please let me know how to know this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi the command to do this is avr32-size.exe [option(s)] [file(s)].
Use it like this:
Navigate to the output directory

avr32-size.exe -Project.elf

The latest Studio build should do this by default when rebuilding the complete Project. This will show up in the output tab.(Open with View->Output or Alt+2